# How to store large numbers in MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB with the native node driver and need to accurately store numbers that may be larger than the int maximum 2147483647. I will need to be able to increment the number as I am tracking usage. What are my options?

I am using Mongoose. The problem I am having is that when I `$inc` past 2147483647 it converts the number to a double. How can I force Mongoose to use the 64-bit long int `NumberLong`?

My schema looks like this

```
var schema = new Schema({
    ...
    usedBandwidth: {type: Number, min: 0, default: 0}
});
```

And my `$inc` looks like this

```
model.Account.update(
    {_id: this.account},
    {$inc: {usedBandwidth: this.size}},
    function (err, doc) {}
);
```

Comment: I just added some more info and code

Comment: If you need even greater numbers than **Double** or **NumberLong**, you may be interested in the [**NumberDecimal/Decimal128** type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77705737/488666).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can now do this in Mongoose with the [`mongoose-long`](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-long) plug-in.

```
require('mongoose-long')(mongoose);
var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
var schema = new Schema({
    ...
    usedBandwidth: {type: SchemaTypes.Long, min: 0, default: 0}
});
```

Comment: How to use this plug-in when you are using es6?

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB has a native 64-bit long integer type, usually called `NumberLong` (at least in the MongoDB javascript shell/driver). If you're using the node-mongodb-native driver, I believe it is just called `Long` (though I am not certain of this, someone please correct me if I'm wrong). `$inc` works as expected against fields of type `NumberLong`.

Comment: $inc does not work as expected with Mongoose (note: not Mongo, but Mongoose) for delta values equal to or bigger than 2^31. Then, they suddenly end up being converted to Doubles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your numbers will not be more than `[-2^63 to 2^63-1]` you will be fine with Long constructor in mogodb (take a look to this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/data-types/#long). But keep this into account, `bigint` in javascript can represent numbers of arbitrary precision, more than Mongo 64bits Long type can represent, so take care if you decide to use bigint in your javascript code.

Anyway, if your numbers could be really big you should prefer string type over `Long()` constructor in mongodb.