# Sort Twitter tweet id string as a number on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, twitter, biginteger

I want to store tweets on MongoDB and then find/order them by id, Twitter API provide two IDs types for a tweet, one as a number type and the other a string type because JavaScript (mongo/node) can only have 53 bit integers and Twitter IDs use more than that.

If I store the IDs as numbers the ID get rounded and lost BUT I can sort and find the IDs with a criteria as "greater than" and "less than".

If I sotre the IDs as strings the ID number get stored as it should BUT I can't find (select) ids with a criteria of "less than" or "greater than" and sorting is a mess because it is sorting the "field" as a string, so "10" shows before "3" because it has "1" at the beginning.

I need to store this IDs and I want to be able to select them with a criteria as "less/greater/equal/than" and sort them by that "field" as numbers...

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NumberLong](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong) to store 64 bit integers.

Comment: Great, that works from the console, but what about node.js/mongoose?
I found this library but I'm not quite sure: https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-long

Comment: @RodrigoPolo I am not a node.js expert but this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617272/how-to-store-large-numbers-in-mongodb-with-node-js should help.

Comment: Thanks to you I already have read that question and then implemented and it works like a charm by only loading that module and changing the model/schema, no more code to change so I'm extremely happy, many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to prepend number with zeroes and store it as a strings, like

```
000000010
000000003
```

so you can store long IDs and use you greater/less/equal conditions

Comment: Storing and comparing longs is more efficient than strings. I agree prefixing zeros might help.

Comment: @bsd my answer is no silver bullet :), it could be helpful for some situation when you have very numbers, fo example

Comment: Though this breaks once the identifier gets long enough that it takes more digits to save as a string than you have used as padding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, use:

```
ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1);
```