# How would you store a number larger than the max 64 bit int in mongoDb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

The number is larger than 9223372036854775807 - too big for NumberLong, which is mongo's native 64-bit long type.  What's the best way to do this/the best field type?

Is it possible to preserve any of the querying functionality of a smaller integer (such as `{$lt}`)?

The big numbers are being generated by bignumber.js, and I'm using mongoose to interact with mongoDb.

Comment: As a string ? String can be longer and store bigger numbers. But you have to converti to and from string.

Comment: Yeah I'm considering that - but I'd love to be able to run $max and $lt queries.  Also considering storing two fields: the whole number quotient of `x/2^63`, and `x%2^63` - then I could query for max by combining params on both fields

Comment: thats exactly how people do it in SQL databases http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the only viable/safe option would be to store such big numbers as a `string` and serialize it back and forth between the application and MongoDB when read/written. However, you will loose the ability to use MongoDB built-in functions that work with numbers (you can still cast the values to numbers, but it won't be safe anymore).

Answer (score 0):

Since **MongoDB 3.4**, it is possible to use [**`NumberDecimal`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) type (also documented as `Decimal128` on MongoDB & Mongoose docs) following the [IEEE 754 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

It has the ability to store maximum and minimum values in the order of **10^6144** and **10^-6143**, and supports **34 decimal digits** of precision
([source](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/bson-data-types-decimal128/)).

Tested with Mongoose 6.6:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const StatisticsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    someMetric: { type: mongoose.Types.Decimal128, default: 0 },
    ...
}
```

Storing a Decimal128 value in DB requires doing:

```
statistic.someMetric = new mongoose.Types.Decimal128(someNumber.toString());
await statistic.save();
```

It supports all the MongoDB operators I could test so far (`$gt`, `$lt`...) and even aggregation pipelines with operators like `$sum`.

On the NodeJS side, to overcome `Number` type limitations ([safe integers up to 2^53-1, i.e. ~9 quadrillions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)), you can use builtin [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) if you don't need decimals. Overall, the conversions between `BigInt` (JS side) & `Decimal128` (Mongo side) can be cumbersome (e.g. you may have to remove trailing ".0000" from `Decimal128` numbers retrieved from DB), however such an approach was definitely a viable option for my use case.