# Validation failed trying to add a number prop into a json and then uploading it into a db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user schema that gets the data from the random user api. I use some of that data and add it into a schema, no problem doing that. But i want to add a new prop into the json called score that is a random number between 7.5 and 10. By doing this i get that the validation for the score prop in the schema failed.

Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "You must enter a gender"],
  },
  name: {
    first: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must enter a first name"],
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "You must enter a last name"],
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "You must enter an email"],
  },
  dob: {
    age: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "You must enter an age"],
    },
  },
  score: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, "You must enter a score"],
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Person", PersonSchema);
```

And here is my populate db file:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const PersonModel = require("./models/person");
const connect = require("./db/connect");

const url = "https://randomuser.me/api";

function generateUserJson() {
  const promise = axios.get(url);
  const dataPromise = promise.then((response) => response.data);
  return dataPromise;
}

const generateRandomScore = (min, max) => {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};

generateUserJson()
  .then((data) => {
    insertUserIntoDb(data.results);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const insertUserIntoDb = async (data) => {
  data.score = generateRandomScore(7.5, 10);
  console.log(data);
  try {
    await connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    await PersonModel.deleteMany();
    await PersonModel.create(data);
    console.log("User added");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

The json after adding the score prop looks like this:

```
[
  {
    gender: 'male',
    name: { title: 'Mr', first: 'Eetu', last: 'Manni' },
    location: {
      street: [Object],
      city: 'Nilsiä',
      state: 'Northern Savonia',
      country: 'Finland',
      postcode: 77242,
      coordinates: [Object],
      timezone: [Object]
    },
    email: 'eetu.manni@example.com',
    login: {
      uuid: '39d2687b-7af8-4203-9b34-f05d2ab74bc8',
      username: 'brownfish992',
      password: 'request',
      salt: 'DO7Gjdn2',
      md5: '49bfe3910055219f30a30f82b8683e71',
      sha1: 'd3a75a6653ed3e032b1683a419ebd6960c075d5a',
      sha256: '4ee03ac4d668f1b5ebf2187cfe0f223be422fb1daadb365566616a14d7844a32'
    },
    dob: { date: '1947-02-11T18:26:04.592Z', age: 75 },
    registered: { date: '2008-07-02T05:41:34.752Z', age: 14 },
    phone: '03-674-277',
    cell: '045-658-75-87',
    id: { name: 'HETU', value: 'NaNNA661undefined' },
    picture: {
      large: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/86.jpg',
      medium: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/86.jpg',
      thumbnail: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/86.jpg'
    },
    nat: 'FI'
  },
  score: 9.394881677107008
]
```

And the error message looks like this: `Error: User validation failed: score: You must enter a score at ValidationError.inspect`

Comment: Am I missing something? You are adding data to `User` model, but the schema you posted is for `Person`.  It's confusing, did you added wrong code snippet?

Comment: My bad, @ShivamSood, i changed some names to post it here and fu*** up. That's not the problem tho, that's just an editing problem that i made copying the original code. Already edited.

Comment: Might have to do with numberLong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617272/how-to-store-large-numbers-in-mongodb-with-node-js

Comment: The `score` property is outside the JSON object - outside the closing curly brace,